# Colspan of 1.5 in a table

Tags: html-table

Is it possible with HTML/CSS to create a table with three columns, where one row has only two cells. However, instead of one cell of that row being 66% (colspan="2") and the other being 33%, both to be 50% (so errh, colspan="1.5" which doesn't work as expected)

To illustrate what I mean:
[image]

What I am talking about is the row which is in bold red, is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure, just like the following:

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

td {
height: 20px;
width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

td {
height: 20px;
width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Single line border Table